# register_post_type comment is not working

Tags: custom-post-types

I have created a custom post type by using `register_post_type` function. Here is my code, but it's not showing the comment meta for the post add new page.

I added other things like, excerpt, thumbnail, author, those are all working fine, but comments alone not working.

```
register_post_type( 
                    'tickets', 
                    array( 'labels' => array( 
                            'name' => __( 'Help and Support' ), 
                            'singular_name' => __( 'Help and Support' ) ), 
                            'public' => true, 
                            'has_archive' => true, 
                            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ))
                    );
```

**Got Reason**

I found the reason, why its not there in the edit post. When a user submits a ticket from the front end,  he/she will be the author of the post(ticket). So, the post authors have right to add comments in the back end. For administrator don't have the right to "add a new comment" in it.

So my question extends one more step. 
 Is there any function to get permission to comment on the edit post(ticket), which is submitted by a user from the front end?

I(administrator) have to get permissions to add a new comment on the post edit page.

Comment: Have you published a "ticket"? If not, create an dummy item then check for comments.

Comment: Yes I published a dummy post and checked it already.

Comment: I don't know the mistake  what i missed here.

Answer (score 1):

Check "Screen Options" in the top right corner of the editor.  Ensure that Comments is checked in the list.

Comment: I checked it. It was checked there already

Comment: No, your answer is not helped me